# Multiple clickable options in cursor adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

Hello everyone,
              I am developing an application. Their is a cursor adapter which holds different view like image , number, date etc. I want to add a image inside this adapter. By clicking on this image we can perform different task ( open another activity ). But we can also click on our adapter. So what I want is an adapter which is click able , and inside this adapter I want an image button which is also click able but perform different operation. I tried to set the onclickListner of that image button inside cursor and inside bind view . But only image button remain click able ( not adapter ). Hope you got my problem. Need a serious solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post explains how to add clickable areas inside your list items, separate from clicking the whole item: http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/